# Изменение value +/-1000 по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="first-range range-container">
    <div class="text">
        <p>Сумма займа <span id="give-money"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="range-input">
        <a href="#" id="minus-money"><img src="img/minus.png" alt=""></a>
        <input id="money" type="range" min="3000" max="15000" step="1000" value="4500">
        <a href="#" id="plus-money"><img src="img/plus.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>                          
</div>
<div class="second-range range-container">
    <div class="text">
        <p>Срок займа <span id="give-day">1 <span>день</span></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="range-input">
        <a href="#" id="minus-day"><img src="img/minus.png" alt=""></a>
        <input id="day" type="range" min="31" max="40" step="1" value="5">
        <a href="#" id="plus-day"><img src="img/plus.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>`введите сюда код`
</div>
```

Не получается сделать складывание и вычитание к value по нажатию кнопок.
Значение input принимает, но в String, а прибавить к нему не получается, прибавляются строки и получается не 1000 + 5000 = 6000, а 10005000
Помогите пожалуйста кто-нибудь?

Comment: и какой код тут что-то прибавляет?

Comment: Или вы про это `Number(this.value)+1000` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается, что вы берете значение из инпутов при сложении, а кто сказал, что из value в инпуте на выходе Number? Получается обычная конкатенация.

```js
alert( '1' + 2 ); // "12"
alert( 2 + '1' ); // "21"
alert( '2' + '1' ); // "21"

// Правильней будет привести к нужному типу

const val1 = '100';
const val2 = '500';

alert(+val1 + +val2);

// или

alert(parseInt(val1, 10) + Number(val2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#plus-money').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var count = parseInt($("#money").val()) + 1000;
    $("#money").val(count);
    $("#money").change();
    $('#give-money').text($("#money").val() + ' рублей');
    calculator();
});

$('#minus-money').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var count = parseInt($("#money").val()) - 1000;
    $("#money").val(count);
    $("#money").change();
    $('#give-money').text($("#money").val() + ' рублей');
    calculator();
});
```

Спасибо, смог разобраться, оказывается не правильно использовал parseInt.